# Nginx, huge size of /usr/share/nginx/on

Tags: nginx

I have a debian with WordPress on dedicate server using Nginx.

During a du/df check, I catched une very huge file "/usr/share/nginx/on" with about 400Go size
Is it ok ?

If not, what is this file and how to reduce size ?

Thank

Answer (score 4):

This is an access log, a result of NGINX misconfiguration. This isn't fine.

In your NGINX configuration, you likely have:

```
access_log on;
```

This is *incorrect* and should be changed to the desired path of an access log. (Or simply remove the directive if you don't care about access logs).

Comment: Thanks you, I changeg this setting in my vhost and type service nginx reload. But the file still exists.

Can I delete /usr/share/nginx/on ? Or I have to restart nginx to delete it ?